# fancy box doesnt work when clicked second time

Tags: fancybox

here is the code i used

```
eventClick: function(event) {
$.fancybox({
                'transitionIn': 'none',
                'transitionOut': 'none',
                'href': event.url,
    });
        return false;
},
```

............
 when i click it for the first time it opens fine in a fancybox but when i click again it moves to a new page (event.url).Also there is tooltip being used and it goes null after the fancybox is opened for the first time

Comment: it looks like a js error is triggered somewhere in the process so the scripts stopped working, but this is a guess because you are providing so little information. A link with an example of the issue would be very useful in order to help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to open Fancybox with url. It should work.

```
$('a.yourAnchor').fancybox({ 
    'overlayColor': '#fff', 
    'autoDimensions': true, 
    'hideOnContentClick': false, 
    'scrolling': false 
});
```